# What happens when you run "import tensorflow" in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand why I am unable to run the (latest) TensorFlow properly when I launch use it in a child process.

The parent process runs `import tensorflow`, but unless I do something that feels very hacky, subsequent calls to `sess.run(...)` will hang.

(By the way, here's the thing that is very hacky. The goal is to get TensorFlow working in a `multiprocessing.Process` subclass. By importing Tensorflow only after both `__init__`ing an instance of the subclass and calling `start()`, calls to `sess.run(...)` work.)

For these reasons, I think the issue stems from me calling `import` in the parent process. I'd like to avoid the very hacky workaround. What happens when `import tensorflow` is called that prevents a `tf.Session` from working in a child process?

**Update:**

In simplified code, let me describe what's going on exactly.

Child process hangs on `sess.run(...)`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Subprocess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.model = ...
        self.output = ...
        self.sess = tf.Session(...)
        self.sess.run(...)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.sess.run(self.output)

child = Subprocess()
child.start()
```

But this works:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Subprocess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def run(self):
        self.model = ...
        self.output = ...
        self.sess = tf.Session(...)
        self.sess.run(...)
        while True:
            self.sess.run(self.output)

child = Subprocess()
child.start()
```

This works, too:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Subprocess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self.model = ...
        self.output = ...

    def run(self):
        self.sess = tf.Session(...)
        self.sess.run(...)
        while True:
            self.sess.run(self.output)

child = Subprocess()
child.start()
```

From this, it looks like the problem with launching TensorFlow in a child process is not related to importing TensorFlow (as many SO answers suggest). Instead, the problem is related to using a `tf.Session` in a *child* process that was created in a *different* (parent) process.

I have a hunch a `tf.Session` instance cannot be shared between processes, but the question why still stands.

Comment: Are you using windows? on Windows, the multiprocessing module starts a new Python interpreter and (re)imports the script.

Comment: No I'm using Ubuntu. Actually, now that I think about it, the problem isn't about importing. Will update question

Comment: That's not about *importing* tensorflow. You changed the point at which you *create the session*.

Comment: Correct, which is why I updated the question.